# How to create different API Keys for different user in AWS Api Gateway authenticated via custom authorizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-cognito, api-key, lambda-authorizer

So I tried finding out about this in general (on a conceptual level but still not many results).

What I want is that different users will be provided with a public API and they can only use it if they have their API key (a common thing done by many existing products/companies).

I read that we can create a custom API key on the API gateway which we then can pass along with the headers or query params and it can be verified either via Cognito/Custom Lambda Authorizer, but according to my understanding that is the only API key which will be shared by all users.
I want each user to have their own API key and use that every time they want to make a request through the API.

I read about creating custom API via API gateway on the AWS console itself or configuring Serverless.yml and adding `private:true` in lambda config and while deploying it will generate an API key (but again this is not user-specific, so any user can use this to make calls to the API). (Referred to this video [here](https://youtu.be/n5aSq1L5nIw))

**Also, I have used Cognito as an authorizer but there the flow was different in the sense that the user logged in and got an ID-Token which I used as authentication (which gets expired too). But here I want just to generate an API key that users can simply use anytime and anywhere.**

Comment: With the `id_token` approach, you could use the `refresh_token`, in order to get a new `id_token` once it is expired. Yes `refresh_token` will also expired and you can increase the validity period. On the other hand, it's a good practice to use token which get expired rather than having non-expiry tokens.  YMMV :)

Comment: But with this approach, the `refresh` and `id` tokens are generated only when the user logs in via Cognito pool credentials. But in the case of the API I want to create, he will just get an API key and can use it from anywhere (his custom backend code, no need to login). What to do in this case?